# place the footer at the bottom of a react native Drawer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have tried in many ways to try to position my footer at the bottom of the Drawer ...
If someone knows, can you please tell me, the idea is to place the  component with the Footer text in the lower part (Image)

[image]

I do not put the code of the application with mine, but I put a snack of react native with an added View that is the one that wants to put in the bottom

https://snack.expo.io/@monsadiego/ask-footer-reactnative

component to place on the bottom:

```
   <Text>
        This text in the footer ...
        </Text>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}` to the `DrawerContentScrollView` component and then add a `<View style={{ flex: 1 }} />` in the top of your footer.

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="Help" onPress={() => alert('Link to help')} />
      {/* Add this View */}
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
      <View>
        <Text>This text in the footer ...</Text>
      </View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```